# Как определить кол-во затрачиваемых ресурсов джава приложения

Tags: java

Появилась задача разместить удаленно сервер на хостинге и для определения тарифа нужно узнать сколько ресурсов затрачивает веб сайт сделанный на java. К сожалению в интернете ни одной статьи не нашел на эту теме. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: каких ресурсов? Памяти? Процессора? Места на диске? Тратит когда что делает? Простаивает или под нагрузкой?

Comment: Если задача просто оценить средний суммарный объём потребляемых ресурсов, то она ничем не отличается от замеров для любой другой программы, на любом другом ЯП и делается средствами операционной системы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос поставлен неточно, нужно точнее знать нагрузку, сколько будет запросов, 1 в секунду? или 10000000 в секунду? хост сделан на чистой java? или со спрингом? или с хибернейтом? каждый из этих вариантов даст нагрузку и на память и на процессор
статей в интернете вы и не найдете, тут нужно исходить из конкретной ситуации